# When using the flutter native splash my image icon is not showing

Tags: screen, splash-screen, flutter-native

Screenshot of code and result:

[image: Screenshot of code and result]

I'm trying to make a custom splash using flutter native splash screen but my image is not showing in the center of the splash screen just the background color changed.

I'm expecting the image to be displayed at the center of the splash screen with the blue background.

Answer (score 0):

I think the path of the icon should be without double-quote for example :
your path is "assets/file/icon.png" you should write it like this assets/file/icon.png.
you can watch this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioWob9KnWk4